What is the difference between the two ways of writing useTransition in react-spring?
"use client";

import React, {memo, useEffect, useState} from 'react'
import {animated, useTransition} from "@react-spring/web";


const Test = () => {


  useEffect(() => {
    changeItem()
  }, [])

  const [items, setItems] = useState<string[]>(["1", "2", "3", "4"]);

  const addItem = () => {
    const newItem = `Item ${items.length + 1}`;
    setItems([...items, newItem]);
  };

  const removeItem = () => {
    if (items.length === 0) return;
    const newItems = items.slice(0, -1);
    setItems(newItems);
  };

  const changeItem = () => {
    setItems(["1", "2", "3", "4"])
  }

  const [transitions, api] = useTransition(items, () => ({
    from: {opacity: 0},
    enter: {opacity: 1},
    leave: {opacity: 1},
    config: {duration: 1000}
  }))

  const transitionsTest = useTransition(items, {
    from: {opacity: 0},
    enter: {opacity: 1},
    leave: {opacity: 1},
    config: {duration: 1000}
  });

  return (
    <div>
      <div>
        <button onClick={addItem}>Add Item</button>
        <button onClick={removeItem}>Remove Item</button>
        <button onClick={changeItem}>Change Item</button>
      </div>
      <div>
        {transitions((style, item) => (
          <animated.div style={style}>{item}</animated.div>
        ))}
      </div>
      <hr/>
      <div>
        {transitionsTest((style, item) => (
          <animated.div style={style}>{item}</animated.div>
        ))}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default memo(Test)

I just started learning and referred to the example in the document, that is transitions, but it doesn't work. animated.div will never be displayed because it is always style="opacity: 0;" 
Then I checked some articles on the Internet and found another way to write it, which is transitionsTest, and found that it can be used normally.
I'm confused as to why the two writing methods lead to different results. I checked the typescript types of the two and found no difference.
package.json file
"dependencies": {      
    "@next/mdx": "^13.4.4",
    "@react-spring/web": "^9.7.3",
    "@reduxjs/toolkit": "^1.9.7",
    "@types/node": "18.15.11",
    "@types/react": "^18.3.1",
    "@types/react-dom": "^18.3.0",
    "eslint": "8.38.0",
    "eslint-config-next": "^14.2.3",
    "immer": "^10.0.4",
    "next": "^14.2.3",
    "normalize.css": "^8.0.1",
    "react": "^18.3.1",
    "react-dom": "^18.3.1",
    "react-redux": "^8.1.3",
    "redux": "^4.2.1",
    "typescript": "^5.4.5",
    "use-immer": "^0.9.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "sass": "^1.61.0"
  }

Can anyone explain why?

According to the docs, there's no difference. In the examples section, there's a link to a Basic Transition codesandbox example. I tested both approaches, and both works as expected. https://www.react-spring.dev/docs/components/use-transition

@RoarS. I created a codesandbox where this issue still persists. I'll consider filing an issue.
